# Why are my prices showing up as unformatted (minor units) in a view on a search index?

Tags: commerce, search

Bit of an odd one here, I am experimenting with the Search API, Search DB and Views. I have a view based on Commerce Products. The view works, along with most of it's facets (but that's another story).

I'm running into a strange issue. I have a view based on a search index using Search API and Search_DB. I have access to all the fields that I indexed, but price is presented as the unformatted price in minor units. It is pulled in as "Indexed Commerce Product Price>> Amount (Price >> Amount)"

The issue I'm having is that it's displaying price as 98,000 rather than $980

Why is the formatting changing? and what's the right way to pull that info into my search view? D-Commerce wants the prices in minor units for it's own internal formatting. I have a regular non-search view which has the correct price...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, if it's a Views view, check you field formatter within the view admin page.  You could also hook into it somehow (I'm not entirely sure how, possibly alter the query), to divide the price by 100, but only for formatting.

Comment: that's one answer, eventually resolved through UI change.